# Generalization of "sock shoes lemma"

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove:

> Let $G$ be a group, and let $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in G$ be any elements. Show that
> $$(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n)^{-1} = x_n^{-1} \cdot x_{n-1}^{-1} \cdots x_1^{-1}.$$

Here is my attempt.

> We proceed by induction on $n$. When $n = 1$, the statement reduces to $x_1^{-1} = x_1^{-1}$, which is true. When $n = 2$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> \left(x_1 x_2\right)\left(x_2^{-1} x_1^{-1}\right) = \left(x_1 \left(x_2 x_2^{-1}\right) \right) x_1^{-1} = \left(x_1 e\right)x_1^{-1} = x_1 x_1^{-1} = e.
> \end{align*}
> As $x_1 x_2 \in G$ and $G$ contains inverses, it suffices to prove that $x_2^{-1} x_1^{-1}$ is a right inverse of $x_1 x_2$, so we conclude that $\left(x_1 x_2\right)^{-1} = x_2^{-1} x_1^{-1}$. Now suppose inductively that for some $n \geq 2$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> \left(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n\right)^{-1} = \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{-1} = \prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} x_{n - i} = x_n^{-1} x_{n-1}^{-1} \cdots x_1^{-1}.
> \end{align*}
> It then follows by the $n=2$ case and the induction hypothesis that
> \begin{align*}
> \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i\right)^{-1} = \left[\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n x_i\right) x_{n+1}\right]^{-1} = x_{n+1}^{-1} \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^{-1} = x_{n+1}^{-1} \left(\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} x_{n-i}^{-1} \right) = \prod\limits_{i=-1}^{n-1} x_{n-i}^{-1} = \prod\limits_{i=0}^n x_{n+i-1}^{-1},
> \end{align*}
> which closes the induction.

How does this look? One thing I'm a bit worried about is my use of association in the first line of the $n=2$ case. My understanding of the generalized associative law is that "any way of parenthesizing the product of four terms will give the same result," so I can invoke associativity to use any of them. If the correct interpretation is that I can "shift the parentheses" once, then this will require more work. Is the first interpretation correct?

Comment: Your proof looks good. Regarding your concern about associativity, I guess you can do $(ab)(cd) = ab(cd) = a(bc)d$.

Comment: @angryavian I'm not sure what the second step here says, though: is it just treating $ab$ as some other field element?

Comment: It's just $(xy)z=xyz$.

Comment: Ok, so is my statement that I can just "pick" a parentheseization incorrect?

Comment: It is correct that you can just ["pick" a parenthesization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Generalized_associative_law); I'm just saying that this fact can be shown by applying the basic definition of associativity multiple times.

Comment: In being hyperformal about this, one might not write "$ab(cd)$," which does not specify how $a$, $b$, and $cd$ are grouped in pairs.  If you know  $x(yz)=(xy)z$ for all $x$, $y$, $z$, you can deduce $(ab)(cd) = a(b(cd)) = a((bc)d) = (a(bc))d$, taking $x=a$, $y=b$, $z=cd$ in the first equality, $x=b$, $y=c$, and $z=d$ in the second, and $x=a$, $y=bc$, and $z=d$ in the third. (The first equality happens to be why "$ab(cd)$" is unambiguous, and the third equality is why "$a(bc)d$" is unambiguous.)